# Progress Bar exception in Windows forms application

Tags: c#, multithreading, youtube, progress-bar

I'm trying to update the progress bar of my windows forms application,which is basically an application to download youtube videos. However I get an exception called 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' on the progressbar method. Please help me solve this. Thanks! :)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBarOverall.Minimum = 0;
        progressBarOverall.Minimum = 100;
        IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videos = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(textBox1.Text);
        VideoInfo video = videos.First(p => p.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4 && p.Resolution == Convert.ToInt32(cboResolution.Text));//converts video quality
        if(video.RequiresDecryption) //Checks if video requiures decryption before downloading the URL 
            DownloadUrlResolver.DecryptDownloadUrl(video);//
        VideoDownloader downloader = new VideoDownloader(video, Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath + "//", video.Title + video.VideoExtension));
        downloader.DownloadProgressChanged += Downloader_DownloadProgressChanged;
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => { downloader.Execute(); }) { IsBackground = true };
        thread.Start();
 }



private void Downloader_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
    {

        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
        {
            progressBarOverall.Value = (int)e.ProgressPercentage;
            percentagelabel.Text = $"{string.Format("{0:0.##}", e.ProgressPercentage)}%";
            progressBarOverall.Update();
        }));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
progressBarOverall.Minimum = 0;
progressBarOverall.Minimum = 100;
```

You mean maximum for the second one?

```
progressBarOverall.Minimum = 0;
progressBarOverall.Maximum= 100;
```